# Primitive ordered collection in java

Tags: java, collections

Trove library provides some fast primitive collections, eg `Map`, `List`, but it does not have any ordered collection, eg `SortedMap`, `TreeSet`. Is there a library that provides those collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/ for some giant ordered structures, but perhaps not all that you want.

Comment: This looks like the right thing to use (from the documentation). The "giant collections" is not the focus, it seems.

Answer (score -1):

There is also `LinkedMap` and `ListOrderedMap` from the [Common Collection](http://commons.apache.org/collections/userguide.html#Ordered%20Maps) library.

```
OrderedMap map = new LinkedMap();
map.put("FIVE", "5");
map.put("SIX", "6");
map.put("SEVEN", "7");
map.firstKey();  // returns "FIVE"
map.nextKey("FIVE");  // returns "SIX"
map.nextKey("SIX");  // returns "SEVEN"
```

Comment: The question asked about collections for primitive types, though.